# So what exactly is the difference between a carbon pencil and a graphite pencil?

Tags: pencils

What is the exact difference between a carbon pencil and a regular graphite pencil? I tried looking it up but nothing really told me.

Comment: Look at [this](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3016/what-exactly-are-carbon-pencils) question and answer.. To sum up Carbon pencils are pencils that contain amorphous carbon (together with other ingredients). They can produce deep black surfaces similar to charcoal but with the comfort (nonscratchyness) of a regular pencil (as compared to charcoal which has a weired scratchy feel when drawing).